# Cannot Change Properties of Controls inside an UIView that was Loadedfrom NIB

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, layout

I am not sure why this is happening.

In my application, I have

1. ViewController.swift
2. CustomUIView.swift
3. CustomUIView.xib

In my ViewController.swift

```
var customView: CustomUIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomUIView", owner: self, options: nil).first as CustomUIView;
customView.setupControl();
self.view.addSubview(customView);
```

In my CustomUIView.swift I tried to change the properties of a UIButton created in the CustomUIView.XIB such as this

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UILabel!

 func setupControl()
 {
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 30, width: 320, height: 240); //THIS DOES NOT WORK

    label.text = "BLABLABLA"; //THIS WORKS
 }
```

I can only modify the property of the UIButton from the InterfaceBuilder.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Auto Layout? If yes, you can't set the frame, because the constraints will override the frame setting. To change the frame, you must set the constraints.

Comment: Hello, sorry I didnt pasted my code properly, Thanks for your answer though. (I have now modified the code) But the problem is that I am unable to move the Label, size the label, I can only change it's text.